# Why SideEffect is neccessary?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

When I delete this method used in the Google theme class, there is no change. Google documents are also incomprehensible when explaining this topic as usual. Different articles have confused me with different explanations. Is there truly a ***simple explanation*** for why we need to use this effect?

```
@Composable
fun Theme(...) {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(color = backgroundColor)
    }
    ....
}

@Composable
fun Theme(...) {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background

    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(color = backgroundColor)
    ....
}
```

Comment: You can check https://jetc.dev/slack/2021-09-04-why-need-sideffect.html

Comment: As far as I understand, its purpose is to let all methods run without stopping at a certain point, and then let the side effects run